# How to convert json to php array and only pull specific value from json

Tags: php, json

How to insert `JSON / PHP` array into `MYSQL`

**Here is the `JSON` values:**

```
{"siteCurrentPowerFlow":
   {
        "updateRefreshRate":3,
        "unit":"kW",
        "connections": 
          [
            {"from":"PV","to":"Load"},
            {"from":"GRID","to":"Load"}
          ],
        "GRID":{"status":"Active","currentPower":65.63},
        "LOAD":{"status":"Active","currentPower":82.37},
        "PV":{"status":"Active","currentPower":16.74}
   }
}
```

**here is the array in `PHP` I got:**

```
Array ( [siteCurrentPowerFlow] => Array ( [updateRefreshRate] => 3 [unit] => kW [connections] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [from] => PV [to] => Load ) [1] => Array ( [from] => GRID [to] => Load ) ) [GRID] => Array ( [status] => Active [currentPower] => 51.68 ) [LOAD] => Array ( [status] => Active [currentPower] => 79.43 ) [PV] => Array ( [status] => Active [currentPower] => 27.75 ) ) )
```

how do I insert this into `mysql` from `PHP`?

I assume I need to use a `foreach` loop, but I don't know how to format the `foreach` loop

```
$arrContextOptions = [
 'ssl' => [
   'verify_peer' => false,
   'verify_peer_name' => false
 ]
];
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
$decoded_data = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($decoded_data);
```

Comment: what values of this array do you want to insert into database? What is the table structure?

Comment: I need to insert 
`"GRID":{"status":"Active","currentPower":65.63}`

MYSQL: id, currentPower (2 columns in mysql)|

When i do:

`$decoded_data = json_decode($urld, true);
$data = $decoded_data["siteCurrentPowerFlow"]["GRID"];
print_r($data);`

I get the correct array: 
`Array ( [status] => Active [currentPower] => 65.63 )`

How to insert only this to mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to insert "GRID":{"status":"Active","currentPower":65.63} MYSQL: id, currentPower (2 columns in mysql)| When i do: $decoded_data = json_decode($urld, true); $data = $decoded_data["siteCurrentPowerFlow"]["GRID"]; print_r($data); I get the correct array: Array ( [status] => Active [currentPower] => 65.63 ) How to insert only this to mysql

```
$decoded_data = json_decode($json_data,true);

$id = ... // set your id
$current_power = $decoded_data['siteCurrentPowerFlow']['GRID']['currentPower']; // fetch data from array

// connect to your db
$mysqli = new mysqli(...); // put your connection config here
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("connection error: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//Prepared statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (id, current_power) VALUES (?,?)"; // change columns to your table schema
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('id', $id, $current_power); //type definition i for integer (id column) , d for double (current_power column). Bind your variables
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

decode your json string

```
$data = (array) json_decode('put your json data here');
```

Comment: `$decoded_data = json_decode($urld, true);
    $data = $decoded_data["siteCurrentPowerFlow"]["GRID"];

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  echo $data["currentPower"];
}`

i get : 65.6365.63

how to insert this then into mysql

Comment: what value get in $value

Comment: `$decoded_data = json_decode($data, true);`
`$data = $decoded_data["siteCurrentPowerFlow"]["GRID"];`

`foreach ($data as $key => $value) {`
  `$currentPower = $data["currentPower"];`
`}`

echo `$currentPower;`

now i can simply do a normal mysql insert.